PDF Rotate PdfAnnotation to an Arbitrary Angle
I would like to be able to rotate a PdfAnnotation to an arbitrary angle.  In this case, I am trying to rotate a PdfPolyGeomAnnotation (i.e. Polygon).  I am using IText 8
I beleive that this is possible based on this example 1  and this example 2 as well as a hand drawn polygon that I then rotated.
In Sample-orig.pdf, there are (4) test polygons.
The first is a control polygon "PlacePolygon1" - no rotation applied.
The second polygon uses "PlacePolygon2" - this attempts to add the structures to match the polygon in "Sheet Sample-test.pdf" also using the method in Example 1
The third and fourth polygons uses "PlacePolygon3" and  "PlacePolygon4" respectively - this attempts to follow methods in example 2
What is interesting is that the second polygon is actually rotated (can be selected)  but is also corrupted and does not show.  If a modification is done to this polygon, the corruption is removed and the polygon shows correctly (see Sheet Sample-adjusted1.pdf).
From what I see, the length of the Appearance Dictionary entry (AP) are different between the corrupted polygon and the correct polygon.
Sheet Sample-orig.pdf length is 8
Sheet Sample-adjusted1.pdf length is 78
Sheet Sample-test.pdf length is 113
This tells me that something is missing but I cannot tell what or how to provide the missing information.
Can I get some help in figuring out how to correctly rotate all PdfAnnotations that can be rotated?
Description of associated files
Sheet Sample-orig.pdf : the original output from the program
Sheet Sample-adjusted1.pdf : same as Sheet Sample-orig.pdf except that the problem polygon was slightly moved and then relocated (up arrow once, down arrow once).
Sheet Sample-test.pdf : A PDF with a hand drawn polygon that has been manually rotated.  This shows the desired result.
public static void PlacePolygon2(PdfPage pdfPage)
{
float rotation = 15.0f;
float x = 700f;
float y = 1000f;
float w = 300f;
float h = 100f;

float[] verts = new []
{
    x          , y,
    x + w - 50f, y,
    x + w      , y + h,
    x + 50f    , y + h,
    x          , y
};

Rectangle r = new Rectangle(verts[0], verts[1], w, h);

PdfPolyGeomAnnotation poly = 
    PdfPolyGeomAnnotation.CreatePolygon(r, verts);

PdfFormXObject xo = null;

poly.SetColor(DeviceRgb.RED);
poly.SetInteriorColor(DeviceRgb.GREEN.GetColorValue());
poly.SetOpacity(new PdfNumber(0.4));
poly.SetStrokingOpacity(0.7f);


// this section is intended to mimic the
// information for a manually placed
// rotated polygon
// start here

float rot = FloatOps.ToRad(rotation);
AffineTransform af = 
    AffineTransform.GetRotateInstance(rot, verts[0], verts[1]);

float[] mx = new float[6];

af.GetMatrix(mx);
// mx[4] = -671f;
// mx[5] = -1286f;

PdfArray pdfArray = new PdfArray(mx);

PdfArray pdfArray2 = new PdfArray(new float[] {r.GetX()-100f, r.GetY()-100f, 500f, 500f });

Rectangle bb = new Rectangle( r.GetX() - 100f, r.GetY() - 100f, 500f, 500f);

Collection<KeyValuePair<PdfName, PdfObject> > col = 
    new Collection<KeyValuePair<PdfName, PdfObject>>();

col.Add(new KeyValuePair<PdfName, PdfObject>(PdfName.BBox, pdfArray2));
col.Add(new KeyValuePair<PdfName, PdfObject>(PdfName.Matrix, pdfArray));

poly.Put(new PdfName("Rotation"), new PdfNumber(rotation));

xo = new PdfFormXObject(bb);
xo.Put(PdfName.Matrix, new PdfArray(pdfArray));

PdfExtGState gs3 = new PdfExtGState();
gs3.SetFillOpacity(.6f);
gs3.SetStrokeOpacity(0.7f);
gs3.Put(PdfName.Type, PdfName.ExtGState);

PdfExtGState gs2 = new PdfExtGState(gs3.GetPdfObject());

PdfDictionary pd1 = new PdfDictionary();
pd1.Put(new PdfName("BBGS"), gs2.GetPdfObject());

PdfExtGState gs = new PdfExtGState();
gs.SetLineWidth(2f);
gs.Put(PdfName.ExtGState, pd1);
gs.Put(PdfName.Type, PdfName.ExtGState);
gs.Put(PdfName.BorderColor, new PdfArray(new float[] { 1, 0, 0 }));
gs.Put(PdfName.Color, new PdfArray(new float[] { 0, 0, 1 }));

PdfResources res = new PdfResources(gs.GetPdfObject());
res.SetProcSet(new PdfArray(new List<PdfObject>(){new PdfName("PDF")} ));

xo.Put(PdfName.Resources, res.GetPdfObject());

poly.SetNormalAppearance(xo.GetPdfObject());

// end here

poly.SetFlag(0);
poly.SetName(new PdfString("poly1"));

poly.Put(PdfName.Type, PdfName.Annot);


pdfPage.AddAnnotation(poly);

}


// ordinary, non-rotated, polygon
public static void PlacePolygon1(PdfPage pdfPage)
{
    float rotation = 15.0f;
    float x = 200f;
    float y = 1000f;
    float w = 300f;
    float h = 100f;

    float[] verts = new []
    {
        x          , y,
        x + w - 50f, y,
        x + w      , y + h,
        x + 50f    , y + h,
        x          , y
    };

    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(verts[0], verts[1], w, h);

    PdfPolyGeomAnnotation poly = 
        PdfPolyGeomAnnotation.CreatePolygon(r, verts);


    poly.SetColor(DeviceRgb.RED);
    poly.SetInteriorColor(DeviceRgb.GREEN.GetColorValue());
    poly.SetOpacity(new PdfNumber(0.4));
    poly.SetStrokingOpacity(0.7f);

    pdfPage.AddAnnotation(poly);

}


// rotation of polygon version 2
public static void PlacePolygon3(PdfPage pdfPage)
{
    float rotation = 15.0f;
    float x = 1200f;
    float y = 1000f;
    float w = 300f;
    float h = 100f;

    float[] verts = new []
    {
        x          , y,
        x + w - 50f, y,
        x + w      , y + h,
        x + 50f    , y + h,
        x          , y
    };

    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(verts[0], verts[1], w, h);

    PdfPolyGeomAnnotation poly = 
        PdfPolyGeomAnnotation.CreatePolygon(r, verts);

    poly.SetColor(DeviceRgb.RED);
    poly.SetInteriorColor(DeviceRgb.GREEN.GetColorValue());
    poly.SetOpacity(new PdfNumber(0.4));
    poly.SetStrokingOpacity(0.7f);

    poly.Put(PdfName.Rotate, new PdfNumber(15.0));

    pdfPage.AddAnnotation(poly);

}

// rotation of polygon version 3
public static void PlacePolygon4(PdfPage pdfPage)
{
    float rotation = 15.0f;
    float x = 1700f;
    float y = 1000f;
    float w = 300f;
    float h = 100f;

    float[] verts = new []
    {
        x          , y,
        x + w - 50f, y,
        x + w      , y + h,
        x + 50f    , y + h,
        x          , y
    };

    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(verts[0], verts[1], w, h);

    PdfPolyGeomAnnotation poly = 
        PdfPolyGeomAnnotation.CreatePolygon(r, verts);

    poly.SetColor(DeviceRgb.RED);
    poly.SetInteriorColor(DeviceRgb.GREEN.GetColorValue());
    poly.SetOpacity(new PdfNumber(0.4));
    poly.SetStrokingOpacity(0.7f);

    poly.Put(new PdfName("Rotation"), new PdfNumber(15.0));

    pdfPage.AddAnnotation(poly);

}


Thank you for your help.  but, forgive me, but I cannot translate the information above into useful C# code.  When I look at the PDF's provided, there is a great deal more PDF code than the above.  Can I get a bit more explanation?

It has taken a lot of trial and error but I developed a code sequence that allows the rotation of a polygon (pre-defined in this case but can be extended to be generic).  Following is this code for future reference and for anyone else looking to be able to rotate a polygon.  Note that this code, I think, can be extended to also rotate other annotations.  Also, if there are any places where this code can be improved, please let me know.
public void PlacePolygon10(PdfDocument doc, PdfPage page,
    float x1, float y1)
{
    Color fColor = DeviceRgb.RED;
    Color bColor = DeviceRgb.BLUE;

    float bdrOp = 0.6f;
    float filOp = 0.2f;

    float bdrWidth = 5.0f;

    float rotation = 45.0f;

    double rotate = FloatOps.ToRad(rotation);

    float x = x1;
    float y = y1;
    float w = 300f;
    float h = 100f;

    float cenX = x + w / 2;
    float cenY = y + h / 2;

    float[] verts = new []
    {
        x          , y,
        x + w - 50f, y,
        x + w      , y + h,
        x + 50f    , y + h
    };

    float[] pathout;

    getOffsetPath(verts, bdrWidth / 2, EndType.CLOSED_POLYGON, out pathout, 10.0f);
    Rectangle rBB = getBoundingRect(pathout);

    float[] mx = new float[6];
    Point[] pxIn = rBB.ToPointsArray();
    Point[] pxOut = new Point[pxIn.Length];
    AffineTransform af = AffineTransform.GetRotateInstance(-rotate, cenX, cenY);

    af.GetMatrix(mx);
    af.Transform(pxIn, 0, pxOut, 0, 4);

    Rectangle rPoly = getBoundingRect(pxOut);

    PdfPolyGeomAnnotation poly =
        PdfPolyGeomAnnotation.CreatePolygon(rBB, verts);

    poly.SetRectangle(new PdfArray(rPoly));

    PdfArray pdfArray = new PdfArray(mx);

    PdfFormXObject xo = new PdfFormXObject(rBB);
    xo.Put(PdfName.Matrix, pdfArray);
    xo.Put(PdfName.FormType, new PdfNumber(1));

    PdfDictionary pds = new PdfDictionary();
    pds.Put(PdfName.Type, PdfName.Border);
    pds.Put(PdfName.W, new PdfNumber(5));
    pds.Put(PdfName.S, PdfAnnotation.STYLE_DASHED);
    pds.Put(PdfName.D, new PdfArray (new float[] { 5, 3, 10, 3 }));

    PdfExtGState gs = new PdfExtGState();
    gs.Put(PdfName.Type, PdfName.ExtGState);
    gs.SetFillOpacity(filOp);
    gs.SetStrokeOpacity(bdrOp);
    gs.SetLineWidth(bdrWidth);

    PdfResources res = new PdfResources();
    res.AddExtGState(gs);

    res.SetProcSet(new PdfArray(new List<PdfObject>() { new PdfName("PDF") } ));

    xo.Put(PdfName.Resources, res.GetPdfObject());

    PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(xo, doc);

    canvas.SaveState();
    canvas.SetExtGState(gs);
    canvas.SetLineDash(new float[] { 5, 3, 10, 3 }, 0);
    canvas.SetFillColor(fColor);
    canvas.SetStrokeColor(bColor);
    drawPath(verts, canvas);
    canvas.ClosePathFillStroke();
    canvas.RestoreState();

    poly.SetNormalAppearance(xo.GetPdfObject());
    poly.SetBorderStyle(pds);
    poly.SetColor(bColor);
    poly.SetInteriorColor(fColor.GetColorValue());
    poly.SetStrokingOpacity(bdrOp);
    poly.Put(new PdfName("FillOpacity"), new PdfNumber(filOp));
    poly.Put(new PdfName("Rotation"), new PdfNumber(rotation));
    poly.Put(PdfName.Type, PdfName.Annot);
    poly.SetFlags(PdfAnnotation.PRINT);
    poly.SetDate (new PdfString(new PdfDate(DateAndTime.Now).GetW3CDate()));
    poly.SetName(new PdfString("Poly 10"));

    page.AddAnnotation(poly);
}

private void getOffsetPath(float[] verts, double offset,
    EndType et, out float[] pathout, float factor = 1)
{
    List<List<IntPoint>> pathin = new List<List<IntPoint>>();
    List<IntPoint> pintlist = convertToIntPoints(verts, factor);

    ClipperOffset co = new ClipperOffset();
    co.MiterLimit = offset * 10;
    co.AddPath(pintlist, JoinType.MITER, et);
    co.Execute(ref pathin, offset * factor);

    pathout = convertToFloatArray(pathin[0], factor);
}

private List<IntPoint> convertToIntPoints(float[] verts, float factor = 1)
{
    List<IntPoint> pintlist = new List<IntPoint>();

    for (int i = 0; i < verts.Length; i += 2)
    {
        pintlist.Add(new IntPoint((double) verts[i] * factor, (double) verts[i + 1] * factor));
    }

    return pintlist;
}

private float[] convertToFloatArray(List<IntPoint> pathOut, float factor = 1)
{
    float[] verts = new float[pathOut.Count * 2];

    for (var i = 0; i < pathOut.Count; i++)
    {
        verts[i * 2] = pathOut[i].X / factor;
        verts[i * 2 + 1] = pathOut[i].Y / factor;
    }

    return verts;
}

public Rectangle getBoundingRect(float[] verts)
{
    int count = 0;
    if (verts.Length < 4) return null;

    double minX = verts[0];
    double minY = verts[1];
    double maxX = verts[0];
    double maxY = verts[1];

    for (var i = 2; i < verts.Length; i += 2)
    {
        count++;

        if (verts[i] < minX) minX = verts[i];
        else if (verts[i] > maxX) maxX = verts[i];

        if (verts[i + 1] < minY) minY = verts[i + 1];
        else if (verts[i + 1] > maxY) maxY = verts[i + 1];
    }

    return new Rectangle((float) minX, (float) minY, (float) (maxX - minX), (float) (maxY - minY));
}

private static Rectangle getBoundingRect(Point[]  pts)
{
    if (pts.Length < 2) return null;

    double minX = pts[0].x;
    double minY = pts[0].y;
    double maxX = pts[0].x;
    double maxY = pts[0].y;

    for (var i = 1; i < pts.Length; i++)
    {
        if (pts[i].x < minX) minX = pts[i].x;
        else if (pts[i].x > maxX) maxX = pts[i].x;

        if (pts[i].y < minY) minY = pts[i].y;
        else if (pts[i].y > maxY) maxY = pts[i].y;
    }

    return new Rectangle((float) minX, (float) minY, (float) (maxX - minX), (float) (maxY - minY));
}

private void drawPath(float[] verts, PdfCanvas canvas)
{
    canvas.MoveTo(verts[0], verts[1]);

    for (var i = 2; i < verts.Length; i += 2)
    {
        canvas.LineTo(verts[i], verts[i + 1]);
    }
}

